# CakePHP: Showing database on a public page

Tags: cakephp, view, controller

So I have an admin panel and now I am trying to make a public page that will show "categories" and comes with a filter that shows the "products" under them. This is in my CategoriesController

```
   public function main(){

            $this->set('categories',$this->Category->find('all'));
```

And this is my main.ctp in the view

```
<table>
<h1>Categories</h1>
<tr>
<th>name</th><th>Products</th>
</tr>
<? foreach($Categories as $row): ?>
<tr><td>
<?=$row['Category']['name']?>

</td><td>
<a href="../todo/products/filter/<?=$row['Category']['id']?>">Products</a>
</td></tr>



<? endforeach; ?>
<a href="http://webdesign4.georgianc.on.ca/~100141468/comp2084/todo/Categories/add/"> Add a Category</a>
```

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong here? I keep getting an error on the foreach

Comment: you do realize that many programming languages are case sensitive, dont you?

Comment: Aside from using short tags and alternative syntax :)

Comment: Where am I going wrong with case sensitivity? This is no doubt why most of my stuff is not working correctly.

Comment: yeah, you should really really work with the documentation and tutorials first. your link is also very wrong und un-cakeish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using the variables in the same case sensitive manner you declare them in.

i will give you a hint: Categories !== categories

Comment: no - follow the guidelines on how to write proper code for a start. than you will be fine. PHP as well as cake: http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/901/CakePHP-Conventions - for beginners it is helpful to bake your code first. to see how it is done.

Comment: Thanks. I am still having trouble with the filters and foriegn keys. No doubt the filters are not working because of the forign keys not working. NOT DOUBT! Because I am screwing up on the case sensitivity. Thanks again